# How to get the list of all the select dropdowns in html page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I need to get a array/list of all the select dropdowns in a HTML page. Any idea how I can achieve this using jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the basics of jQuery, you should learn jQuery before trying anything.

Comment: Yeah, I am a newbie to jQuery!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
var $select_array = $('select');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the magic:

```
var allSelects = $('select');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to this.

```
var dropdowns = [];

    $('option').each(function(){
       dropdown.push($(this))
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all of the selections made by various drop down lists on a page you would do it like:

```
var selections = []

jQuery('select').each(function(){
    selections.push(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

See my working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wMLw8/)